# Android: how to get the timestamp related to a measured characteristic of a BLE heart rate GATT service?

Tags: android, timestamp, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, bluetooth-gatt

I'm doing as the [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) says and all work perfectly fine. I can discover the heart rate service from the GATT server and then get all the updates from the heart rate characteristic samples.

However, is there a characteristic to get the timestamp related to each heart rate sample? Getting the System.currentMillis() whenever I get a sample seems too inaccurate to me. I'd want something like this

```
 if (UUID_HEART_RATE_TIMESTAMP.equals(characteristic.getUuid()))
```

EDIT:
I'm referring to the example at the line

```
if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
```

where the app can parse the data received by the heart rate sensors. Is there a way to parse a timestamp value together with the heart rate? The result I need is something like a couple of values, not the single hear rate.

(timestamp, heart rate)

Comment: can you add the log before checking condition what are the values you are getting

Comment: The checking condition is invented because at the moment I don't know which UUID is the one related to the timestamp.

Comment: I've edited the question to add more details

Answer (score 0):

Receiving the *exact* timestamp related to a BLE heart rate measurement is impossible since this is not part of the [BLE Heart Rate Service GATT specification](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=239866):

> 3.4 Requirements for Time-Sensitive Data
>
> The Heart Rate Measurement characteristic contains time sensitive data and is
> considered a time-sensitive characteristic, thus the following requirements apply:
>
> **Since this service does not provide for a time stamp to identify the measurement time
> (and age) of the data**, the value of the Heart Rate Measurement characteristic shall be
> discarded if either the connection does not get established or if the notification is not
> successfully sent to the Client (e.g., link loss).

As indicated by the documentation, you can assume that transmitted measurements are 'fresh' and therefore using the receiving device's timestamp upon arrival is a good approximation.

Unfortunately, RR-intervals might need more precision and are contained within the same not-timestamped measurements. Assessing the timestamp of individual RR-intervals might require some more trickery since multiple intervals are bundled together per measurement.

> If more RR-Interval values are measured since the last notification than fit into one
> Heart Rate Measurement characteristic, then the remaining RR-Interval values should
> be included in the next available Heart Rate Measurement characteristic.
>
> If there is no available space in the internal buffer of the Heart Rate Sensor, it may
> discard the oldest RR-Interval values.

You might thus have to use the transmission interval to assess whether or not measurements have been dropped, which impacts your ability to timestamp RR-intervals.

> In typical applications, the Heart Rate Measurement characteristic is notified
> approximately 1 time per second and includes the Heart Rate Measurement Value field
> and, if supported, the RR-Interval field.